# Android Notification Image Sometimes not displaying

Tags: android, amazon-s3, httpurlconnection

I have coded to fetch the image from amazonaws and show it in the expanded view of notification.below is the code

```
         try { 
               URL url = new URL(imageUrl);            
               HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();    
               connection.setDoInput(true);           
               connection.connect();         
               InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();           
               return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();      
               return null;
           }
```

The same code works and showing the image in some devices and not in others at the same time.
Images which are not displaying getting exceptions like as below

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host 
"examples3.s3.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname

 java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to 
 examples3.s3.amazonaws.com/1.2.3.4:5(some ip showing, this is for the only 
 reference)
```

Comment: convert your imageURL into Bitmap

String encodedImage1 = " ";
encodedImage1 = Base64.encodeToString(bm,Base64.DEFAULT);
use Convert you photo to String. Then Save

Comment: thankyou for your answer, but the exception is coming on connection, after only successful connection i can convert the image as any format